# Can I save a window size to a specific size on default? Not full screen

Tags: 11.10, firefox, window

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to set a specific window size for all windows that open to default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-for-all-windows-that-open-to-default)

How I get Firefox to remember size and position of the window.

Comment: Using Unity or not? If under Unity then see http://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-for-all-windows-that-open-to-default/107968#107968