# How to set a specific window size and placement for all windows that open to default

Tags: unity, compiz, window

I want my windows to be a specific size (not full screen) and to be in the middle of the screen by default. When I close the application and re-open it, it will be the dimensions I want it to be by default. Is there an easy way to do that? I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 and the Unity desktop enviroment.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I don't know if you can simply make all windows behave the same, but you can individually. We'll use Thunderbird as an example.

Make sure you have ccsm installed: Open a terminal (Press <kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>T</kbd>) and enter

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

Open ccsm. You'll be using the Place Windows and Windows Rules plugins in the Window Management section.

[image: Compiz Window Managment]

First, go into Place Windows, select the Fixed Window Placement tab and Select New.

[image: Fixed Window Placement screen]

Enter the program name (class=xxxx) and set the starting X and Y coordinates. The coordinates start from the top left corner of the screen. This tells the program where to open on the screen.

[image: Enter placement rules]

Next go to the Windows Rules plugin and select the Size Rules tab and new.

[image: Window Rules screen]

Enter the program name (class=xxxx) and set the X and Y size. This tells the program what size to open the program in pixels (pixels wide x pixels high).

[image: Enter size rules]

Now, open the program you just did this for and it should open where and how big you want it to everytime.
[image: Open your program]

Note that you will have to do this for every program you want to open in a specific place and a specific size. You can also use one without the other, for instance always having a program open in a specific place but not having it's size defined.

Comment: That's a great documented answer @James! Do you know if i can set a shortcut, e.g. Super+I to set the current open window to an specific size? e.g. 1280x900

Comment: Never mind, i've just found: `wmctrl -r :ACTIVE: -e 0,-1,-1,1280,900` and added as a Custom Shortcut within Keyboard Shortcuts settings :)

Comment: You do need to log out and log in again.

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.04 (maybe also in other versions) you have also to install package "compiz-plugins" in order to have the mentioned features.

Comment: To found the class name of a specific window, you can open a terminal, execute `xprop` and click with mouse inside the window.

Answer (score 5):

Check out gdevilspie from the universe repository! You can use it to set a rule for your window by application name and use that rule to resize, unmaximize... really anything window-related.

Gdevilspie Step-By-Step:

1. Click the Add button
2. Type "Firefox" in the top-most textbox
3. In the "Matching tab", check "Window name"
4. In the box labeled "equal(s)" type: "Firefox"
5. Under actions checkmark:

   - Unminimize
   - Geometry (set to the desired geometry - you can also use the command-line program xwininfo to get the width/height of a window when you have it resized to where you want it. The same goes for xposition and yposition)
6. Click Save
7. Click the Start button
8. Click "Start devilspie daemon automatically at login" if you want the fix to be semi-permanent.
9. Hang on to your hat!

Answer (score 2):

Open

```
~/.config/compiz-1/compizconfig/config
```

under the `[general]` section edit or add the size option:

```
[general]  
profile =  
integration = true  
size = 1200, 800
```

Comment: What about Firefox, where does it save this information?

Answer (score 1):

Firefox not remembering the size and position on the screen. Solution work for me: Press  Super key...open dash...click compiz ....click on unity plugin...experimental tab...automaximize value = 100. that worked for me.