# How can I configure the terminator terminal to always be on top?

Tags: command-line, workspaces, terminator

I was able to set up the terminal to expand the whole monitor width but I would like for it to stay on the top of the screen even if I go to another workspace.  If I hit F12 to drop it down when I am on a different workspace, it brings me back to the workspace I opened the terminal in and then puts the terminal window on the bottom of the monitor screen.

Below you will see my config:

```
[global_config]
  enabled_plugins = LaunchpadCodeURLHandler, APTURLHandler, LaunchpadBugURLHandler
  hide_from_taskbar = True
  always_on_top = True
  tab_position = bottom
  sticky = True
[keybindings]
  hide_window = F12
[profiles]
  [[default]]
    background_darkness = 0.93
    palette = "#000000:#cc0000:#4e9a06:#c4a000:#3465a4:#75507b:#06989a:#d3d7cf:#555753:#ef2929:#8ae234:#fce94f:#729fcf:#ad7fa8:#34e2e2:#eeeeec"
    background_type = transparent
    foreground_color = "#00ff00"
[layouts]
  [[default]]
    [[[child0]]]
      position = 0:24
      type = Window
      order = 0
      parent = ""
      size = 1700, 464
    [[[terminal3]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 1
      parent = child0
    [[[terminal2]]]
      profile = default
      type = Terminal
      order = 0
      parent = child0
[plugins]
```

Here is what happens via screen shot.  I was on workspace 1, then switched to workspace 2, and hit F12.  As you can see, I was brought back to WS 1 with the terminal at the bottom.

[image: Before workspace change]

[image: After workspace change and hitting F12]

Comment: There is a setting in preferences to 'show on all workspaces'; that option is present in the 12.04 default version. That seems to work for me. Now when you go to a different workspace you can press f12 and stay on that workspace.

Comment: @Mik I have that set but it doesn't stop it from occurring.

Comment: I'm sure you're probably set on the Terminator Terminal, but I thought I'd mention [Guake](http://guake.org/). It works the way you describe.

Comment: Interestingly, the fact that the setting I mentioned works on Xfce and not on your system (Unity/compiz) probably means that the terminator workspaces setting doesn't take account of the compiz viewports system properly. Perhaps you could somehow use ccsm to tweak the behaviour of terminator.

Comment: @Kupiakos I used Guake before but I switched to Terminator.

Comment: @Mik I am not sure what would need to be changed with ccsm.

Comment: I'm not greatly experienced with ccsm, but [this general question might be helpful regarding window rules](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-for-all-windows-that-open-to-default).

Comment: @Mik I tried your suggestion it worked but didn't.  It worked at keeping the window the right size but now I cannot switch full screen mode if needed.  I didn't test the workspace switching part out since I need to be able to go from full screen to the size I set.

Comment: Interesting, there is also a program called `devilspie` that can be used to manipulate windows and their positions, but I don't know if that would help you.

Comment: Another possibility might be [tilda](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tilda/).  In its 'general' section of its preferences setting, there is 'display on all workspaces', which works as you describe.  If you want to 'multiplex' the `tilda`, you can use `screen` or (what I prefer) `tmux`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switching from Ubuntu to Xubuntu fixes this issue.

Comment: Gotta love those one line answers that should be comments

Answer (score -1):

You can set easily define Terminator's appearance and behaviour by right-clicking anywhere in an active window and them choosing "Preferences". Play around a little and you'll surely find a satisfying setting.

Comment: that doesn't address saving layouts.  If you go into preferences and then layouts, it doesn't say save current layout.  It doesn't even ask you to modify it.  Also, your "answer" doesn't address the terminals behaviour between workspace which isn't in preferences either.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to have the app open on all workspaces but you can take the window with you to another workspace by pressing alt+tab+ctrl+arrows.

Comment: I am not saying open on every workspace.  When I minimize the app with F12, move to another workspace, and then hit F12 again, I am brought back to the first workspace with the terminal at the bottom.  Very annoying.