# How to start Gummi (GTK+ based application) maximized?

Tags: gtk, maximized

Is there something I could add to the `Exec` line ìn `gummi.desktop` which would do the trick?

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Gummi
GenericName=LaTeX Editor
Comment=Simple LaTeX Editor
Exec=gummi %F
Icon=gummi
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Office;
StartupNotify=true
MimeType=text/x-tex;
```

https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gummi/

http://dev.midnightcoding.org/projects/gummi

https://launchpad.net/~gummi/+archive/gummi

Comment: If you're running Unity you could try [configuring window rules with Compiz.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-for-all-windows-that-open-to-default) Other window managers offer similar settings.

Comment: thx, yes I'm using Unity and am aware of CCSM -- but generally try to keep my usage of it to a minimum...

Answer (score 2):

**Please Note:** the answer below will work with window managers such as xfwm4, metacity, and others, but will not with `compiz`, because of the way the desktop and windows are handled (being divided into viewports). As [mhc](https://askubuntu.com/users/81372/mhc) noted, you will have to use ccsm, as explained in [comment above](https://askubuntu.com/questions/276163/how-to-start-gummi-gtk-based-application-maximized#comment346491_276163), and refer to [this askubuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-for-all-windows-that-open-to-default).

---

You don't need to add anything to the `.desktop` file, just edit the config file in your home folder.

Find `$HOME/.config/gummi/gummi.cfg` and set the dimensions to your screen size and it will launch maximised. The dimensions will vary according to your maximum resolution; for example they could be 1280x1024, 1920x1080, etc.

Here is the original section in `$HOME/.config/gummi/gummi.cfg`.

```
[Global]
config_version = 0.6.1
mainwindow_x = 244
mainwindow_y = 233
mainwindow_w = 792
mainwindow_h = 558
```

As an example, I would change 792 and 558 to 1280 and 1024, so that it would launch maximised next time. Edit the file and then relaunch `gummi`. Whatever you put in will be adjusted by the program when it launches, so don't worry about specifying the exact values.

If you mess up the configuration file, just delete it and it will be respawned when `gummi` launches.

---

You could also use `devilspie`, which is in the repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install devilspie
```

Now create a `~/.devilspie` folder if it doesn't already exist, and create a profile for gummi, so that when gummi runs, it will trigger `devilspie` to maximise the window. Name the file `gummi.ds` and place this in it:

```
; gummi maximise

(if (is (window_class) "Gummi") (maximize) )
```

However, `devilspie` must be added to startup applications, as it needs to be running.

It is worth trying `devilspie` as it is a very useful application for manipulating chosen windows, but may not work if you are running compiz.

Comment: no dice. set mainwindow_w/h to my max. (and current) resolution, also set mainwindow_x/y to 0. any further ideas? was it a good idea setting mainwindow_x/y to 0?

Comment: or - does it require a reboot? (or logout-log-back-in)

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty I edited it- the mainwindow_x, y weren't supposed to be 0. It does work for me- just put your current resolution for the mainwindow w and h and save the file. Then relaunch gummi. Perhaps you have a different window manager than me; I'm on Xfce using xfwm4.

Comment: I'm on unity; I'll keep observing (do a reboot eventually) and report back.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty I don't think a reboot will make any difference; because windows are considered differently with compiz (viewports, etc), `ccsm`  is probably your best bet, as has already been mentioned by someone else.

Comment: hmm; so would the changes I made to ´gummi.cfg` have made any difference at all (I noticed none so far); meaning, should I roll back to the original settings (e.g. by deleting the file), or can I just leave it as-is with the modified settings (cuz they anyone don't make a difference with/in compiz) ?

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty You can leave it as it is, and remember you can delete it in the future if you ever encounter any problems.

Comment: @nuttyaboutnatty In my edit I mention `devilspie`, which is worth trying.