# How can I change the size and position that an application appears when first launched?

Tags: 12.10, window-manager, window

When ever I launch Chrome it manifests at a specific size at the top left corner of my screen. Everytime I have to manually resize it and position it in the center of the screen.

**How can I change the window size and position on the screen upon launch?**

Comment: This question was already answered. Please refer to this:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-for-all-windows-that-open-to-default

Answer (score 0):

If so, you can specify a window position at launch with Compiz' "Place Windows" plugins:
"System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager -> Window Management -> Place Windows"

Try to adjust the "Placement Mode" ("General" tab) first, it seems like you have "Center" selected there, the default is "Smart".