# Changing the location of (specifically) the home folder window on screen when opening it

Tags: nautilus, screen, monitor, window, window-manager

Whenever I use my shortcut to open the home folder it's always positioned at the bottom left of my screen as shown below.

[image: Bottom left]

How can I open it in such a way that it would pop up in the center like this?

[image: Center]

Comment: Can we just go to `ccsm` and change how the window is placed?

Comment: Hi theAnsweris3, did you notice the answer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set a specific window size and placement for all windows that open to default](http://askubuntu.com/questions/107951/how-to-set-a-specific-window-size-and-placement-for-all-windows-that-open-to-def)

Comment: see suggested duplicate, specifically accepted answer. Ubuntu uses compiz to manage windows and there are plugins for that.

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy yeah, kind of a dupe, but just not *exectly*. The answer there fits that question + this one, but not every answer to *this* question is an answer to that one, hence no exact dupe, this one only asks for one specific situation, and not everyone will want to install ccsm for that.

Comment: @JacobVlijm procedure for setting up placement and sizing for windows is exactly the same, and answers are made general enough.   On the other hand, what is the difference between installing `xdotool` and `ccsm` ? Either tool is not in default Ubuntu installation, so "not everyone will want to install ccsm for that"  isn't a good argument in this case - user still has to install something. On the other hand, `ccsm` has advantage in the fact that the tool is specific for Ubuntu, so it would be a far better fit for a solution than `xdotool`

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I guess I don't need to mention ccsm is a much more sensitive tool then xdotool. I didn't try this one, but many ccsm settings add processor load, while the answer below adds nothing at all. The fact that we are even discussing it proves we don't have an exact dupe here. The only question we have to ask ourselves is if every possible answer here fits the one you mention to be a dupe. It doesn't. Even the one below doesn't. Let's move this discussion to chat if you like further discussion.

Comment: @JacobVlijm   Unless you have any serious proof, I consider your claim that `ccsm` adding processor load is empty. I personally run multiple compiz pluginz and never there's been high usage from a `compiz` process.  I don't see what you mean by the fact that `ccsm` is "sensitive" either. There's plenty of other posts which ask about window placement, which also mention `ccsm`'s plugin, which testifies to the fact that people use it perfectly fine without issues. `xdotool` doesn't have any issues either, but I don't see your reason to attack `ccsm`.

Comment: Does it only happen when opening by using shortcut or happen even when you click the icon?

Answer (score 1):

#### The simplest, pragmatic solution

To make sure the window always appears on the same poissition, create a shortcut to get it done:

1. Install `xdotool`, to position the window:

   ```
   sudo apt install xdotool
   ```
2. Add the following command to a keyboard shortcut:

   ```
   /bin/bash -c "nautilus ~ && sleep 0.5 && xdotool getactivewindow windowmove 300 300"
   ```

   Where you need to replace `300 300` by the actual position (x/y) where you want the window to appear: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command above to a shortcut you like.

   [image]

#### Note

This works nicely, but there is a small chance that if your system is heavily occupied, the window will not appear in time so the `xdotool`command will run in vain. Writing a separate script to prevent this from happening once a year seems overkill though in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Window placement is handled by `compiz` in Unity and to fine control it's behaviour, you need to install `ccsm` or compizconfig-settings-manager.

Install it with this command

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Open it and go to **Place windows** plugin page. Under the section **Placement mode** select **Centered** to have the desired effect.

The default selection is *smart* I think. You can also try **Cascade** which is the default case in Windows systems afaik.

[image: window placement settings image]